# If a variable is allocated on the stack in an inline function using alloca, is its reference valid after the inline function returns?

Tags: c++, g++, inline

I know that the compiler *may*, not *shall* unroll `inline` functions into the calling function to avoid the overhead associated with calling out-of-line functions. I also know, however, that `inline` functions are linked differently than out-of-line functions, so I can't expect them to act the same way, exactly.

While I am actually using C++, I'm developing a program using an api in which it is convenient to make use of C macros that look something like:

```
#define func_alloca(ptr) do { *ptr = alloca(size); memset(*ptr, 0, size); }
```

In the interest of not repeating code several times in different functions, it would be useful for me to be able to functionalize a series of these `alloca` calls. My question is, (in gcc specifically, since `alloca` is implementation-defined,) can I initialize variables on the stack using `alloca`, inside an `inline` function, and count on them to work outside? Here's an example of what I want to do:

```
inline void uses_alloca(type*& ptr){
    // do stuff
    func_alloca(ptr);
}

void calls_inline(){
    type *local_ptr;
    uses_alloca(local_ptr);
    // is local_ptr valid?
}
```

If it does work, will it *always* work? As in, not only when the compiler chooses to unroll the `inline` function into the calling function?

Edit:

My guess is that this probably *will* work in fact, since the `alloca` call is already valid outside the `do{}` local scope contained in the macro, and since, if I understand correctly, a function doesn't actually have a different level of scope in C++ than a `do{}` block. My question remains: is this the way `alloca` is supposed to work in gcc? Is this defined behavior?

Comment: `inline` doesn't change the semantics of what happens in a function.

Comment: Think of it like copy and pasting the code into the call site but wrapping it with `{}` to create a "function scope".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is the use of alloca() not considered good practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018853/why-is-the-use-of-alloca-not-considered-good-practice)

Comment: perhaps have a look at the execute-around idiom, instead.

Comment: @πάντα, this isn't a question of whether it's good practice to use `alloca()` or not. I didn't write the api, I'm just using it.

Whoever voted to close, I'd be happy to clarify this question if I knew where your confusion lay.

Comment: @NathanOliver that would be different... `alloca` space typically lasts until the end of the enclosing function, not the enclosing block. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5407546/memory-allocated-with-alloca-gets-freed-at-end-of-function-or-at-end-of-scope

Comment: @sleeptightpupper I didn't write the code that uses `alloca`, and the linked "good practice" question and answers don't seem to mention inline functions, or much on the use of `alloca` at all. I'm not writing new code that contains `alloca`, and I'm not advocating that practice. Leaving memory management up to the compiler and avoiding "copy/paste" code duplications are both good practices where possible, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: @juanchopanza inline DO change the semantics of what happens in a function, especially with static variables. Static variables in inline functions are local to each place the function is called, so calling such function twice or calling it in a loop won't gave the same result.

Answer (score 5):

Declaring a function `inline` does not extend the scope of the contained variables to the scope, into which it is expanded. So, whatever `alloca` allocates is not at all guaranteed to be valid in the context that has called the *function* `uses_alloca`. If you use the *macro* `func_alloca`, you are fine because the macro text is literally expanded in place. However, the use of `alloca` itself is typically considered a bad practice.

Comment: Scope is irrelevant; it refers to the region of source code in which an identifier is visible at compile time. It's about lifetime / storage duration.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using GCC, the *intended* behavior is that functions with `alloca` in them aren't inlined automatically. From [`tree-inline`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/tree-inline.c#L3560):

```
  /* Refuse to inline alloca call unless user explicitly forced so as
 this may change program's memory overhead drastically when the
 function using alloca is called in loop.  In GCC present in
 SPEC2000 inlining into schedule_block cause it to require 2GB of
 RAM instead of 256MB.  Don't do so for alloca calls emitted for
 VLA objects as those can't cause unbounded growth (they're always
 wrapped inside stack_save/stack_restore regions.  */
```

This of course doesn't take into account:

- Bugs
- The compiler inlining functions anyways because it's not perfect
- Optimization switches, attributes
- Bad luck

The [GCC manual page](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Inline.html) on inline warns that inlined functions are ill-suited for `alloca` and [Why is the use of alloca() not considered good practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018853/why-is-the-use-of-alloca-not-considered-good-practice) has a few horror stories as well.

Essentially if you're worried that inlining may affect the semantics of your code, don't rely on it.